# Inject a href code to a facebook page on chrome using extension or js

Tags: javascript, facebook, google-chrome, html

I manage a group on facebook and banning people who have offending post is pretty hard. You need to go on ban list search for their names and what happens is wait for the results to finish. click gear icon then remove user/ban. Now what I'm trying to do is an extension for chrome to have an easier ban button. 
I manually patched this code for chrome console

```
<div class="UFICommentContent" 
id=".reactRoot[77].[1][2][1]{comment393093797435268_406224232788891}.0.[1].0.[1].0.[0]">
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/josh.e.mason.5" 
   data-hovercard="/ajax/hovercard/hovercard.php?id=1207160525" 
   data-ft="{&quot;tn&quot;:&quot;;&quot;}" 
class="UFICommentActorName" 
id=".reactRoot[77].[1][2][1]{comment393093797435268_406224232788891}.0.[1].0.[1].0.[0].[0][0]" 
aria-owns="js_14" 
aria-controls="js_14" 
aria-haspopup="true">Josh Elijah Mason</a>
<span id=".reactRoot[77].[1][2][1]{comment393093797435268_406224232788891}.0.[1].0.[1].0.[0].[0][1]"> 
</span>
<span data-ft="{&quot;tn&quot;:&quot;K&quot;}" 
id=".reactRoot[77].[1][2][1]{comment393093797435268_406224232788891}.0.[1].0.[1].0.[0].[0][2]">
<span class="UFICommentBody" id=".reactRoot[77].[1][2][1]{comment393093797435268_406224232788891}.0.[1].0.[1].0.[0].[0][2].0">
<span id=".reactRoot[77].[1][2][1]{comment393093797435268_406224232788891}.0.[1].0.[1].0.[0].[0][2].0.[0]">Hello nicole
</span>
</span>
</span>
</div>
```

to include this code another button before the name which is this code

```
<a href=".
<a class="itemAnchor" href="/ajax/groups/members/remove.php?group_id=392480624163252&amp;uid=100001756455088" rel="dialog-post" role="menuitem" title=""><span class="itemLabel">[x]</span></a>
```

which will result like this " [x] Sample User" Click the x will result to a ban pop up notfictication. my problem is to create a code that will search for the user ID and put it in that code, insert the code for every facebook user on a group with their post. it will be easier to ban that way.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UNFhm.png

Answer (score 0):

If you implement it as a user script (GreaseMonkey) you can use it in all browsers. And in the script you can check the URL and if the URL corresponds with your FB group page then using jQuery you can add that code before the user names: `$("selector-for-user-name").before("<your-code-from-above>");`

Actually I recommend to make your code generic, add just a button in front of the user name, add a click event handler in which you retrieve the user name next to the clicked button and call your method.

If you still have any issue going further, leave a comment.

Comment: thanks for the reply. My problem is I don't know how to use jquery right now. and banning a user is based on aid/id value which you can get on the view:source code/rendered page. If they use a custom username like facebook.com/sample user, their user id is embedded in the page. is there a way to scrape their id's and put it automatically on the ban code?

example where the user id is "hovercard.php?id=1207160525" from the inspect element view. > userid

Comment: I said jquery because it seemed easier. But you can use plain JavaScript as well. You should get the user id from the DOM element containing it.